# Bind Kivy Text Input with Function

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have written a kivy script in which I am not able to bind text input with my callback function.

Here I have written a script in which the app will take an email address as text input and then on pressing button it will send an email to the email address.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import webbrowser
from functools import partial
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
import re
import urllib2
import time
import os
import sys
import smtplib
import string
import time
from functools import partial

# Here I have predefine some values already which will be used in script
fromaddr = 'email id will be wriiten in script already'
msg = "hello world"
uname = 'email id will be written in script already'
pword = 'password will be wriiten in script already'

#this is just popup for email sent 
def once_pop(instance):
    popup = Popup(title='NOTE',
                content=Label(text='Email sent',halign='center'),
                size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),auto_dismiss=True)
    popup.open()

#this is my callback function in which email will be sent
#email id will be taken from text input and in callback function email will be sent to that email id

def callback(instance,self):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(uname,pword)
    self.t.text=destinationemailid
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, destinationemailid, msg1)

class TestApp(App):
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')    

        def build(self):
            bx=FloatLayout(size=(300, 300))
            l=Label(text='\nUSE THIS APPLICATION ON YOUR OWN RISK.\nTHIS APP IS MADE BY WARL0CK.\nWE WILL NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANY KIND OF DAMAGE.',font_size=21,size=(470,100),size_hint=(None,None),pos=(0,650), halign='center')
            t=TextInput(font_size=20,size=(470,39),size_hint=(None,None),text='Enter Email Id to you want to send email',pos=(0,580),multiline=False)
            b=Button(text="SEND EMAIL",font_size=18,background_color=[1,1,3,1],size=(250,75),size_hint=(None,None),pos=(0,470))
            b.bind(on_press=once_pop)   
            b.bind(on_release=final)        
            c=Button(text= 'EXIT',font_size=18,background_color=[1,1,1,1],size=(100,75),pos=(330,470),size_hint=(None,None))
            c.bind(on_release=exit)

            bx.add_widget(l)
            bx.add_widget(t)
            bx.add_widget(b)
            bx.add_widget(c)
            return bx
    except:
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        textlabel=Label(text='  INTERNET IS REQUIRED FOR THIS APP.\nPLEASE START INTERNET & RESTART APP.',size_hint=(None,None),size=(410,140), halign='center')
        textbutton=Button(text='Exit',size=(410,80),size_hint=(None,None))
        textbutton.bind(on_release=exit)
        box.add_widget(textlabel)
        box.add_widget(textbutton)
        popup = Popup(title='ERROR !', content=box, size_hint=(None, None), size=(450, 300),auto_dismiss=False)

        popup.open()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what happens when you run this more precisely; simply saying "it doesn't work" doesn't narrow it down much. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Fixed typos and grammar. Snippets are useless for python code.

Comment: Sorry for all.....i just have made a email sending script

Comment: The  [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) states "no distractions" and **no chit-chat**. Including "thanks in advance" twice, so we have to wade through double the amount of unwanted chit-chat, is more than just impolite. Please read the help→tour and follow its advice.